# Documenting scripts with YARD

Tags: ruby, yard

Reading the [YARD documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/README.md) and questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681467/how-to-document-ruby-code) I see this is a very nice tool to document functions, classes, and methods, but I fail to figure out how to document a simple script such as:

```
# @description Read files in folder and print their sizes
# @author Mefitico
require_relative '../lib/my_funcs'


# Check files in folder and print their sizes:
Dir.entries(Dir.pwd).select do |file|
    if File.file?(file) 
        puts "#{file} - #{File.size(file)} bytes"
    end
end

puts "Finished script"
```

Doing so generates no documentation whatsoever because no functions or classes are being defined. But for the project I'm working on, I need to create documentation for several standalone scripts which call for functions defined elsewhere. These scripts need to be documented nicely, and cannot be refactored into functions, modules or classes.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/19465313/3868595, you can wrap above code in the method and add docs to the method.

Comment: @stolarz : Despite the related title, the question and the answer there don't help. That guy needed "especially methods" to be documented, and was missing those due to an error in generating the top-level namespace. Also, defining dummy functions on every step I need documented would be quite a hassle.

Comment: Have you considered a README instead? YARD will doc a README in many flavors. Also while I would recommend breaking the script into digestible pieces via classes and methods nothing prevents you from creating a single module with a single method and including all your documentation there [For Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/BoilingSeashellStack#sample.rb)

Comment: @engineersmnky : If we were to use `.md` files/markup, that would require having separate files to code and document, defeating the purpose of using a doc tool based on comments in code. Nothing technically impedes creating modules with single methods, I was expecting this to be unnecessary and is likely not a solution acceptable for the team, which might prefer creating a custom tool to achieve what is expected. Part of the problem is that documentation was left for later, and a lot of design decisions had already been made, including using such scripts that define no functions/classes.

Comment: @engineersmnky Very nice proof of concept in that link of your though!

Comment: @Mefitico well I guess the only other suggestion I could provide then is `rdoc --main your_file_name.rb` it will atleast document everything as the main index.html page.

Comment: @engineersmnky : for a file like the above, the output of rdoc looks like: `Files:      1

  Classes:    0 (0 undocumented)
  Modules:    0 (0 undocumented)
  Constants:  0 (0 undocumented)
  Attributes: 0 (0 undocumented)
  Methods:    0 (0 undocumented)
  Total:      0 (0 undocumented)
    0.00% documented`  which basically means it does nothing.

Comment: @Mefitico did you actually look at the output? You show 1 file and it says it processed 1 file. `doc/index.html` will show the output of the documentation comments in that file?

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes I looked at it and checked again just to be sure, it creates the page but it contains basically nothing, For the example I've put in the question, no comments are replicated and even the file itself is not shown in the file list section.